# Does asmlinkage function still use registers to pass arguments?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, toolchain, arm64

There is a description about asmlinkage:

> "The asmlinkage tag is one other thing that we should observe about
>   this simple function. This is a #define for some gcc magic that tells
>   the compiler that the function should not expect to find any of its
>   arguments in registers (a common optimization), but only on the CPU's
>   stack. Recall our earlier assertion that system_call consumes its
>   first argument, the system call number, and allows up to four more
>   arguments that are passed along to the real system call. system_call
>   achieves this feat simply by leaving its other arguments (which were
>   passed to it in registers) on the stack. All system calls are marked
>   with the asmlinkage tag, so they all look to the stack for arguments.
>   Of course, in sys_ni_syscall's case, this doesn't make any difference,
>   because sys_ni_syscall doesn't take any arguments, but it's an issue
>   for most other system calls. And, because you'll be seeing asmlinkage
>   in front of many other functions, I thought you should know what it
>   was about.

asmlinkage tell the toolchain that this function doesn't pass argument via general register, but stack. But I found a function in linux kernel "asmlinkage void __exception do_mem_abort()",

arch/arm64/mm/fault.c

```
/*
 * Dispatch a data abort to the relevant handler.
 */
asmlinkage void __exception do_mem_abort(unsigned long addr, unsigned int esr,
                     struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    const struct fault_info *inf = fault_info + (esr & 63);
    struct siginfo info;

    if (!inf->fn(addr, esr, regs))
        return;

    pr_alert("Unhandled fault: %s (0x%08x) at 0x%016lx\n",
         inf->name, esr, addr);

    info.si_signo = inf->sig;
    info.si_errno = 0;
    info.si_code  = inf->code;
    info.si_addr  = (void __user *)addr;
    arm64_notify_die("", regs, &info, esr);
}
```

below is the disassembly:

```
ffffffc000081180 <do_mem_abort>:
ffffffc000081180:   a9b57bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp,#-176]!
ffffffc000081184:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
ffffffc000081188:   12001424    and w4, w1, #0x3f
ffffffc00008118c:   b0005365    adrp    x5, ffffffc000aee000 <init_sighand+0x760>
ffffffc000081190:   52800303    mov w3, #0x18                   // #24
ffffffc000081194:   a90153f3    stp x19, x20, [sp,#16]
ffffffc000081198:   a9025bf5    stp x21, x22, [sp,#32]
ffffffc00008119c:   911860a5    add x5, x5, #0x618
ffffffc0000811a0:   9ba37c84    umull   x4, w4, w3
ffffffc0000811a4:   f86468a6    ldr x6, [x5,x4]
ffffffc0000811a8:   2a0103f3    mov w19, w1
ffffffc0000811ac:   aa0003f5    mov x21, x0
ffffffc0000811b0:   aa0203f6    mov x22, x2
ffffffc0000811b4:   8b0400b4    add x20, x5, x4
ffffffc0000811b8:   d63f00c0    blr x6
ffffffc0000811bc:   350000a0    cbnz    w0, ffffffc0000811d0 <do_mem_abort+0x50>
ffffffc0000811c0:   a94153f3    ldp x19, x20, [sp,#16]
ffffffc0000811c4:   a9425bf5    ldp x21, x22, [sp,#32]
ffffffc0000811c8:   a8cb7bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp],#176
ffffffc0000811cc:   d65f03c0    ret
ffffffc0000811d0:   f9400a81    ldr x1, [x20,#16]
ffffffc0000811d4:   b0004360    adrp    x0, ffffffc0008ee000 <kallsyms_token_index+0x2e00>
ffffffc0000811d8:   2a1303e2    mov w2, w19
ffffffc0000811dc:   aa1503e3    mov x3, x21
ffffffc0000811e0:   91102000    add x0, x0, #0x408
ffffffc0000811e4:   941a8cf8    bl  ffffffc0007245c4 <printk>
ffffffc0000811e8:   b9400a85    ldr w5, [x20,#8]
ffffffc0000811ec:   b9400e84    ldr w4, [x20,#12]
ffffffc0000811f0:   d0004420    adrp    x0, ffffffc000907000 <kallsyms_token_index+0x1be00>
ffffffc0000811f4:   9110c000    add x0, x0, #0x430
ffffffc0000811f8:   aa1603e1    mov x1, x22
ffffffc0000811fc:   9100c3a2    add x2, x29, #0x30
ffffffc000081200:   2a1303e3    mov w3, w19
ffffffc000081204:   b90033a5    str w5, [x29,#48]
ffffffc000081208:   b90037bf    str wzr, [x29,#52]
ffffffc00008120c:   b9003ba4    str w4, [x29,#56]
ffffffc000081210:   f90023b5    str x21, [x29,#64]
ffffffc000081214:   94001f12    bl  ffffffc000088e5c <arm64_notify_die>
ffffffc000081218:   17ffffea    b   ffffffc0000811c0 <do_mem_abort+0x40>
```

It still use x0,x1,x2 the pass the three argument, is it a different behavior for arm64 ?   THX

Comment: I can't see where it passes the arguments in registers.  Can you show the disassembly of the _calling_ function?  Note that asmlinkage won't guarantee to stop functions `pr_alert` and `arm64_notify_die` from being called with register arguments (unless they are themselves declared with asminkage).

Comment: what I tried say is do_mem_abort's three argument were passed via general registers, e.g. addr = x0, esr = x1, regs = x2. So you mean if we have two function asmlinkage a(), normal function b(), normal function c(). calling sequence is b -> a -> c, b can pass argument via register to a, but a can't pass register to c, correct ?

Comment: If b calls a which calls c (as you suggest), and only a() is defined with asmlinkage, then you should see that a's arguments (passed by b) are all on the stack, but c's arguments (passed by a) could be in registers (depending on the calling convention).

Comment: On second thoughts, please ignore my comment.  I am not at all sure that `asmlinkage` does anything at all for ARM64.  A quick glance at the kernel code suggests it might just enforce `extern c` for C++ code, but I am definitely not certain.  Not at all like the i386 code.  Sorry about that, and I hope I did not waste too much of your time.

Comment: THX anyway, it still helps :-)